# Entity Framework Core - What happens to tracked records if CRUD operations are done directly at the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

As I have read the EF Core documentation, I have understood that change tracking works like a cache for tracking entities. I come to realize that some of my DB Admins like to run add/update/delete operations directly to the database. What else could happen to my tracked entities then if they do so? I have a hunch that these tracked entities will go out of sync against the database but I have not confirmed it yet.

Comment: Nothing! So yes, unless you ask EF core to read the database again, they will go out of sync

Answer (score 2):

EF uses optimistic concurrency by default and (as far as I know) does not support pessimistic concurrency (yet). Under the optimistic scenario ... last saved record wins.

You would need Exception checking and reload the data.

For updating..

```
try
{
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

To handle a delete...

```
try
{
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
   var entity = ex.Entries.Single().GetDatabaseValues();
   if (entity == null)
   {
         // Already deleted
   }
}
```

There are also concurrency tokens [ConcurrencyCheck],[TimeStamp]... property attributes for implementing optimistic concurrency.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations